# generating pair of numbers in order

Tags: fortran

I need some help in  generating pair of numbers in orders using FORTRAN code.

The order is like following.

loop_1: 
`1,2  2,3  3,4  4,5  5,6  6,7  7,8  ..... until <= 2000`

loop_2:
`1,3  3,5, 5,7  7,9  9,11  11,13  ........until <=  2000`

loop_3: 
`1,4, 4,7  7,10  10,13  13,17 ..... until <=  2000`

loop_4:
`1,5 5,9 9,13 13,17 17,21 .... until  <= 2000`

.
.
.
.
until loop_100:

I have tried with simple code such as

```
program loopJump
implicit none
!

 integer :: i,j,k

 do k = 1, 6
 do i =  1, 5

    j=(i+k)

   print*, i,"   ",j

 enddo
 enddo

 stop
 end
```

But I can not get as I wanted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your inner variable `i` has to advance by `k`, not by 1, in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. **EDIT:** with correct formatting.

```
program loopJump

  implicit none
  !

  integer :: i,j,k
  integer :: loopend
  character(len=*),parameter :: fmt1 = "('loop_',I1,' ',I4)"
  character(len=*),parameter :: fmt2 = "(', ',I4,', ',I4 )"

  do k = 1, 6
     write(*,fmt1,advance='NO') k,1
     loopend = (2000-1)/k
     do i =  1, loopend

        j=1+i*k
        write(*,fmt2,advance='NO') j,j
     enddo
     write(*,fmt="(2X)")
  enddo

  stop

end program
```

**EDIT2:** After a careful look, it seems Kerrek SB answered this question earlier through a comment above. With that method, the loop would look like this:

```
 do k = 1, 6
     write(*,fmt1,advance='NO') k,1
     do i =  k+1, 20, k
        write(*,fmt2,advance='NO') i,i
     enddo
     write(*,fmt="(2X)")
 enddo
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know fortran, but this pseudo code might help you out:

```
let i := 1
let n := 1

while i <= 100 do
  while n <= 2000 do
    print n
    n := n + i
    print ",", n, " "
  done
  print "\n"
  i := i + 1
done
```

Comment: Your Idea too helped me. Thanks